# I need to deploy vuestorefront to a bucket s3 or amplify,

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify, vue-storefront

I need to deploy vuestorefront to a s3 bucket or amplify, but I have had some problems since vuestorefront has a server on the front end, so I would like to know how I could do this and turn it into a static project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue Storefront requires an active node server, and it's not yet supported to do Lambda deployment yet. We are working on bringing this solution to the framework.